# Link models from different databases

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-fluent-api

I have the following situation: I have a class Company, it is as simple as possible

```
public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I also need to extend the IdentityUser class from ASP. NET Identity Core:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
}
```

Not bad so far. But I also need a class Device :

```
public class Device
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
}
```

Accordingly, we add the Devices property of the `List<Device>` type to the Company class and Users property of the `List<User>` type.

The problem is that I want to separate the data (Device table) from the data of ASP .NET Identity Core in different databases. Table Company I want to put in the database with Auth data. And table Device in other one. How can I tell the Entity Framework that the Company property of the Device class is from another database?

Comment: So, `Company` has *many* `Device`, and `Device` has *one* `Company`?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly

Comment: *How can I tell ...* You can't. One context = one database.

Comment: Please read other answers and comments

Answer (score 1):

If the Company property is from another database, you may need to add a second database context for it, if you haven't already. Something like this:

```
public class CompanyModelContext : DbContext
{
    public CompanyModelContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options){ }
    public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the Device table (the first database) and the User table (the second database) refer to the Company table (the second database) and so EF creates the Company table in both databases.

Comment: Can you use separate contexts? One that contains a DbSet for the Device table and another context that contains DbSets for User and Company?

Comment: Yes I can. But since Company refers to User and Device, the Company table will be created in the first database and in the second one. This is the question: how to tell EF table Company is needed only in one database?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set your EF model like this:

*Companies* table:

```
[Table("Companies")]
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

*Devices* table:

```
[Table("Devices")]
public class Device
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
}
```

*ApplicationDbContext* class:

```
public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Company>(buildAction =>
    {
        buildAction.ToTable("Companies");

        buildAction.HasMany(x => x.Devices)
                   .WithOne(x => x.Company)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    };
}
```

---

I've added `Devices` as a list in `Company` class, then overriding the FK in the method `OnModelCreating`.

Once you delete an item in table `Company`, all items with the same `Id` in table `Devices` (comparing to `CompanyID`) will be delted *automatically*.

Since we use the 2 properties `[Table]` and `[Key]` to define table name and the primary key. So in the `OnModelCreating`, you can ignore to define the name, PK, FK of table `Device`.

---

> Company has many User

In this case:

*User* class:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

*Company* class:

```
[Table("Companies")]
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

*ApplicationDbContext* class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Company>(buildAction =>
    {
        buildAction.ToTable("Companies");

        buildAction.HasMany(x => x.Devices)
                   .WithOne(x => x.Company)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        buildAction.HasMany(x => x.Users)
                   .WithOne(x => x.Company)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    };
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the Device table (the first database) and the User table (the second database) refer to the Company table (the second database) and so EF creates the Company table in both databases.

Comment: @starmucks `Company` table cannot have relationshop one-to-one with `User` table since it has relationship `many-to-one` with `Device` table. You can remove it.

Comment: Well now. Table Company in one database and table Device in another.

Comment: @starmucks Sure. That's how EF works. But once you delete a row in table `Company`, it would make changes to `Users` and `Devices`

Comment: In Your code, the Company refers to the User and Device from the different databases. Thus, the Company table will be created in the first database and in the second one. This is the question: how to tell EF table Company is needed only in one database?